# Asus AMD Laptop keyboard backlight (20.04)

Tags: keyboard, laptop, asus, backlight

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to get my dual boot system set up (Asus Rog laptop with AMD Ryzen 7 and NVIDIA GPU). This in its self has presented its own problems but I have updated my kernel to 5.8 to overcome issues with it.

I'm trying to get my keyboard back lights working with the keyboard short cuts, or even at all and so far have been unsuccessful with the `xset` function I've read about online. Weirdly, my system starts up with the back light disabled. If I suspend the system and resume, they switch on until I power off.

I've found a script which relates to the back lights in etc/acpi, I was hoping I would find a asus folder in the led directory but I do not. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

\# this directory is a symlink on my machine:
KEYS_DIR=/sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight

test -d $KEYS_DIR || exit 0

MIN=0
MAX=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/max_brightness)
VAL=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/brightness)

if [ "$1" = down ]; then
        VAL=$((VAL-1))
else
        VAL=$((VAL+1))
fi

if [ "$VAL" -lt $MIN ]; then
        VAL=$MIN
elif [ "$VAL" -gt $MAX ]; then
        VAL=$MAX
fi

echo $VAL > $KEYS_DIR/brightness
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem, the solution I have found is this. My keyboard is not an RGB model but adds the functionality. I still cannot get the keyboard fn keys to work though.

https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore